# Netbeans module development: How to get a list of all namespaces in the current project?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I'm developing a netbeans module for special code completion features for PHP code. I'm very familiar with java development.

My question is: Which Netbeans API provides information about the current loaded projects (namespaces, classes...) and how can I access this API?

For example: I want to show a list (for code completion) with all classes of a distinct namespace, even if the files are in separate folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have much better chance to get a reply if you posted to `dev@platform.netbeans.org` - a mailing list for NetBeans plugin authors / RCP app delevelopers. https://netbeans.org/community/lists/top.html